# Create a GUI Application using MonoDevelop on OS X

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, mono, monodevelop

I just installed the latest Mono framework and MonoDevelop.

When I create a new solution under C# there is no GUI based application.

How do I create an app that has a GUI and buttons etc

Comment: http://tufnelltech.blogspot.com/2012/01/hello-os-x-from-c-five-steps.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are on Linux or Windows, the project type is called "Gtk# 2.0 Project".  If you are on Mac, there is no visual designer for Gtk#, you will have to code it by hand.

Answer (score 6):

you can create GUI by mono in mac follow these steps:

- File->New->Solution.
- Select C# and then select Gtk# enter a name for your project then click Forward.
- in the solution window at the left side of the window click the arrow next to your project name, then right-click on the MainWindow.cs click open.
- after it opened at the bottom of the window there is (Source code and Designer) click on the Designer, enjoy it you can see a form now.

so if want to add buttons, textboxes, lables,... etc there is a toolbox window at the right of the window.

Answer (score 3):

If you're already familiar with WinForms and C# development using Visual Studio--and if you don't mind developing a GUI without a visual editor--then you can develop a WinForms application in MonoDevelop.

This tutorial should get you started:
http://zetcode.com/tutorials/monowinformstutorial/firststeps/

After creating a new C# solution (File|New > Solution...), add references to System.Drawing and System.Windows.Forms (Project|Edit References...). In the constructor for your Form subclass you can define buttons and other controls. That should get you on your way.

There may still be bugs and odd quirks in MonoDevelop. For example, autocomplete for adding an event handler (such as MyButton.Click += HandleMyButtonClick) works if I insert a space after "+=", but not if I tab. Otherwise the environment should feel familiar.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of bindings for Mono and Cocoa which allow you to build OS X apps using Mono with native looking interfaces.

Some time ago there was the Cocoa# project, which is still shipped with Mono, but is now dead on the water and no longer updated.

However, just a few days ago, I myself asked about the state of Cocoa# and other solutions were highlighted. The best (IMHO) is [Monobj](http://www.monobjc.net/), which also has Monodevelop/IB templates.

Answer (score 0):

Just install Xcode together with MonoFramework and MonoDevelop, then you can use the native iOS interface builder!

MonoDevelop works perfectly (although a little buggy on some functions) with xcode.
During development of say, an iPhone-app, I switch between Monodevelop and Xcode, MonoDevelop for writing all code-behind/delegates etc., and Xcode for designing using the native interface-builder for Mac OSX and iOS apps...

You need:

**MonoDevelop**
http://monodevelop.com/

**MonoTouch (UI framework to interface with CocaoTouch on iOS)**
http://xamarin.com/monotouch

**And of course the actual mono-framework (C# to Obj-C)**
http://www.mono-project.com/

Comment: of cause only if you intend to develop OSX/iOS apps on .NET platform :)

Answer (score 0):

MonoDevelop supports

- [MonoMac](http://www.mono-project.com/MonoMac) for OS X Lion applications

  [MonoTouch](http://xamarin.com/monotouch) for iOS applications